# How can I store data in a dictionary without overriding it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

How can I store data in a dictionary in Python without overriding the existing one?

For example:

```
output = {}

name = raw_input("Enter name")
age = input("Enter your age")
course = raw_input("Enter course")
school = raw_input("Enter school")

output['name'] = name
output['age'] = age
output['course'] = course
output['school'] = school
```

The output is this.

```
{
    "name": "Student 1",
    "age": 25,
    "course": "BSCS",
    "school": "School 1"
}
```

Then, if I add another field, it overrides the existing data.

How can I store it just like this:

```
{
    "students": [
        {
            "name": "Student1",
            "age": 25,
            "course": "BSIT",
            "school": "School 1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Student2",
            "age": 26,
            "course": "BSCS",
            "school": "School 2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Student3",
            "age": 27,
            "course": "BSCE",
            "school": "School 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A key is unique, so if you want to store multiple values in one key, make the value a list or another dict, tuple, custom Object etc..

E.g.

```
my_dict = {}
my_dict["students"] = []
my_dict["students"].append( new_dict )
```

I would consider making a class or using a tuple to store the students data inside the list, however, if you want the JSON like format, you may use other dictionaries like:

```
new_dict = {"name": "Max", "age":12}
my_dict["students"].append( new_dict )
```

In case of an object you'd make something like:

```
class Student(object):

    __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

So now you could do something like:

```
my_dict.append( Student("max", 12) )
```

Comment: the variable `new_dict` is another dictionary inside the list of the root dictionary. In JSON this would look like `{"students": [ {"name":"max", "age": 12} ]}`.

Comment: And I forgot to add the key in `my_dict.append(new_dict)` it should be `my_dict["students"].append(new_dict)`

Comment: Is it possible to use the raw_input as params in class Student?

Comment: @Jayjay sure, why not, that is just a string after all

Comment: How can I use it theraw_input as params in class Student, can you give some code snippet. Sorry. I am a novice in python. Thanks

Comment: I got it @meow using the raw input. Thanks. But for using the class. May I know how to use it. Thanks

Comment: @Jayjay I dont quite understand the question sorry.
If you mean how to use the `raw_input`, this just promts the user to enter something, which is stored as a string inside the assigned variable. 
Now the class is again something different, in this case it just encapsulates the students data. So since we use the constructor to populate the instance variables, you just pass your strings obtained through raw_input ->  `new_student = Student(name, age)`. Obviously you can add the additional values as well.

Comment: I get it @meow. But I have a problem. When I appended the data to the existing data. It's just duplicating the value.

{
    "students": [
        {
            "name": "Student1",
            "age": 25,
            "course": "BSIT",
            "school": "School 1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Student1",
            "age": 25,
            "course": "BSIT",
            "school": "School 1"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Are you sure your input is actually different? You would have to show me your code at this point I guess.

Comment: Yes different input. This is the code:
menu = 0
my_dict = {}
my_dict["data"] = []
new_dict = {}

def store():
 name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
 age = input("Enter age: ")
 course = raw_input("Enter course: ")
 school = raw_input("Enter school: ")

 new_dict['name'] = name
 new_dict['age'] = age
 new_dict['course'] = course
 new_dict['school'] = school

 my_dict["data"].append( new_dict )

while menu != 4:
 menu = int(raw_input("\nEnter your choice: "))
 if menu == 1:
  store()
 elif menu == 2:
  print(my_dict)
 elif menu != 4:
  print("Test")

Did i miss something?

Comment: @Jayjay Try putting the new_dict = {} statement inside the function. Right now you are setting a reference to the same mutable object multiple times. Thus every time you add new_dict to the list it points towards the same object. In a C/C++ language you would put the same pointer, pointing towards the same memory location inside your list, thus any change you make to new_dict will be reflected by all list entries.

Comment: I got it. Thanks, @meow. Yes, the variable new_dict is outside the function, that's why it just overrides the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve it  using the inbuilt `collections` module and a class called `defaultdict` in it.

```
import collections as cl
output = cl.defaultdict(list)
for i in range(n):
    name, age, course, school = map(str, raw_input().split())
    age, key, value = int(age), "student" + str(i + 1), dict()
    value["name"], value["age"], value["course"], value["school"] = name, age, course, school
    output[key] = value
```

As far as the documentation says

> This module implements specialized container datatypes providing alternatives to Python’s general purpose built-in containers, dict, list, set, and tuple.

[Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: Thanks, @Mayank. I used this code snippet. But I have encountered errors during compiling.

Comment: @Jayjay sorry i had some typos, :p please look into the code now.